# RESTful web service on TIBCO BW6.3 and Swagger UI tool

Tags: swagger-ui, tibco-business-works

I recently started to use `TIBCO BW6.3`
I've created a RESTful web service that invokes another SOAP Web service, Hopefully until now.

I want to use a user-friendly tool, called Swagger UI, included in `TIBCO BW6.3`, in order to test my RESTful web service, when i start my application (process that represent my RESTful Web service), i get an exception in the console, and i cannot access the Swagger interface !

The console shows me at the end a message that the application has successfully started, but when i try to use Swagger UI to test my RESTful web service, it doesn't work !!

The followwing is the error :

```
!MESSAGE [com.tibco.bw.binding.rest.swagger.runtime(76)] The addSwaggerHostingConfig method has thrown an exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.replace(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.bw.rest.swagger.service.impl.SwaggerHostingConfigurationConsumer.addSwaggerHostingConfig(SwaggerHostingConfigurationConsumer.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:222)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:37)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:615)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BindMethod.invoke(BindMethod.java:41)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.doInvokeBindMethod(DependencyManager.java:1605)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.invokeBindMethod(DependencyManager.java:1581)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.invokeBindMethod(SingleComponentManager.java:369)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$MultipleDynamicCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:322)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$MultipleDynamicCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:298)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1492)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1413)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1222)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.track(ServiceTracker.java:1158)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:1444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:998)
    at com.tibco.bw.binding.rest.runtime.core.RestServiceBT.init(RestServiceBT.java:373)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWComponentImpl.initializeComponent(BWComponentImpl.java:537)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWComponentImpl.doStart(BWComponentImpl.java:393)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWApplicationModuleImpl.startApplication(BWApplicationModuleImpl.java:390)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWApplicationModuleImpl.onResolved(BWApplicationModuleImpl.java:144)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.api.DependencyDescriptor.onStateChange(DependencyDescriptor.java:83)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.api.ConstituentStateDependency.o00000(ConstituentStateDependency.java:105)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.api.ConstituentStateDependency.onStateChange(ConstituentStateDependency.java:71)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.model.Constituent.setConstituentState(Constituent.java:124)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWSharedModuleImpl.onResolved(BWSharedModuleImpl.java:67)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.api.DependencyDescriptor.start(DependencyDescriptor.java:120)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWModuleEventHandler.deployModule(BWModuleEventHandler.java:562)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWModuleEventHandler.handleBundleEvent(BWModuleEventHandler.java:411)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.ApplicationHandler.addingBundle(ApplicationHandler.java:254)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.ApplicationHandler.addingBundle(ApplicationHandler.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:469)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker.open(BundleTracker.java:156)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.ApplicationHandler.onResolved(ApplicationHandler.java:187)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.api.DependencyDescriptor.start(DependencyDescriptor.java:120)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.ApplicationHandler.handleBundleEvent(ApplicationHandler.java:1568)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.Deployer.addingBundle(Deployer.java:485)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.Deployer.addingBundle(Deployer.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:469)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker.open(BundleTracker.java:156)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.Deployer$1.frameworkEvent(Deployer.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.tibco.bw.binding.rest.swagger.runtime 4 0 2016-05-16 15:09:48.782
!MESSAGE [com.tibco.bw.binding.rest.swagger.runtime(76)] The addSwaggerHostingConfig method has thrown an exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.replace(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.bw.rest.swagger.service.impl.SwaggerHostingConfigurationConsumer.addSwaggerHostingConfig(SwaggerHostingConfigurationConsumer.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:222)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:37)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:615)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BindMethod.invoke(BindMethod.java:41)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.doInvokeBindMethod(DependencyManager.java:1605)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.invokeBindMethod(DependencyManager.java:1581)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.invokeBindMethod(SingleComponentManager.java:369)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$MultipleDynamicCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:322)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$MultipleDynamicCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:298)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1492)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1413)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1222)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.track(ServiceTracker.java:1158)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:1444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:998)
    at com.tibco.bw.binding.rest.runtime.core.RestServiceBT.init(RestServiceBT.java:373)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWComponentImpl.initializeComponent(BWComponentImpl.java:537)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWComponentImpl.doStart(BWComponentImpl.java:393)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWApplicationModuleImpl.startApplication(BWApplicationModuleImpl.java:390)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWApplicationModuleImpl.onResolved(BWApplicationModuleImpl.java:144)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.api.DependencyDescriptor.onStateChange(DependencyDescriptor.java:83)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.api.ConstituentStateDependency.o00000(ConstituentStateDependency.java:105)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.api.ConstituentStateDependency.onStateChange(ConstituentStateDependency.java:71)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.model.Constituent.setConstituentState(Constituent.java:124)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWSharedModuleImpl.onResolved(BWSharedModuleImpl.java:67)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.api.DependencyDescriptor.start(DependencyDescriptor.java:120)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWModuleEventHandler.deployModule(BWModuleEventHandler.java:562)
    at com.tibco.bw.frwk.BWModuleEventHandler.handleBundleEvent(BWModuleEventHandler.java:411)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.ApplicationHandler.addingBundle(ApplicationHandler.java:254)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.ApplicationHandler.addingBundle(ApplicationHandler.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:469)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker.open(BundleTracker.java:156)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.ApplicationHandler.onResolved(ApplicationHandler.java:187)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.api.DependencyDescriptor.start(DependencyDescriptor.java:120)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.ApplicationHandler.handleBundleEvent(ApplicationHandler.java:1568)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.Deployer.addingBundle(Deployer.java:485)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.Deployer.addingBundle(Deployer.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:469)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker.open(BundleTracker.java:156)
    at com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.Deployer$1.frameworkEvent(Deployer.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
15:09:49.585 INFO  [bwEngThread:In-Memory Process Worker-2] c.t.b.p.g.Log.ACMEAppModule.Log - Received Lookup request for OrderID : TESTORDER123
15:09:49.834 INFO  [Thread-30] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300006: Started BW Application [ACMEApp:1.0]
15:09:49.835 INFO  [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: f0806ac5-6f1b-0016-1355-e14504be535b] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - Started by BusinessStudio, ignoring .enabled settings.
```

Could you help me to solve this issue, thanks a lot.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this @Rachid?

Comment: Not yet, do you have a solution, Note that i use TIBCO BW6.3

Comment: Adding JVM argument did not work for you?

Comment: I've already found it, with the port 7779 and when i try to access the Swagger UI, by typing http://localhost:7779/AppName in the browser, it didn't work, do you have any other solution.

Comment: Did it give you the same error or has it changed and led to another issue?

Comment: it gives the same error

Comment: sorry buddy. I only had that much for you then. If it was a new error, i could have helped.

Comment: @RachidKABBAB were you able to resolve your issue? If yes, then can you please share how you did it ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the default port for Swagger in TIBCO. Add a JVM argument to point to the correct port number like this:

```
-Dbw.rest.docport=<your_port>
```

For more details refer to this link:
https://community.tibco.com/questions/i-am-getting-below-error-opening-swagger-document-server-bw6-even-after-i-changed-http